# VS code not running the switch after scanf() function

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, scanf

I am new to programming in C, I take online course and I tried to realize a switch, so all the code is working, but when it gets to the `scanf` function, I type the number of the case, then the terminal displays nothing and returns to the starting point.

If I take off the `scanf` function, it displays the default result at the end of the switch, here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int choixMenu;

    printf("=== Menu ===\n\n");
    printf("1. Royal Cheese\n\n");
    printf("2. Mc Deluxe\n\n");
    printf("3. Mc Bacon\n\n");
    printf("4. Big Mac\n\n");
    printf("Votre choix ? ");

    scanf("%d", choixMenu);

    switch (choixMenu)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("Tu as choisi le Royal Cheese\n");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Tu as choisi le Mc Deluxe\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Tu as choisi le Mc Bacon\n");
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Tu as choisi le Big Mac\n");
            break;

        default:
            printf("Vous n'avez pas rentré un nombre correct (entre 1 et 4)");
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'scanf("%d", choixMenu);' cannot modify 'choixMenu'.  C arguments are COPIED into parameters, so any function 'fun(type value)' cannot mutate 'value'.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the value of `choixMenu` to `scanf`, which is pointless, because that variable does not yet have a meaningful value. Instead, you should pass the address of `choixMenu` to `scanf`, like this:

```
scanf("%d", &choixMenu);
```

That way, `scanf` knows to which memory address to write the result of the input conversion.

Also, it is generally a good idea to verify that the input conversion succeeded before attempting to use the result of the input conversion:

```
if ( scanf("%d", &choixMenu) != 1 )
{
    printf( "Input conversion error!\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```